# considering the terms in the Fibonacci sequence whose values do not exceed four million, find the sum of the even-valued terms

Tags: javascript, html

i am new to solve this type of problems using java script

Each new term in the Fibonacci sequence is generated by adding the previous two terms. By starting with 1 and 2, the first 10 terms will be:

1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, ...

By considering the terms in the Fibonacci sequence whose values do not exceed four million, find the sum of the even-valued terms.

this is my java script

```
function solution()  
{  
var fibno = [ 1, 2 ], sum = 0;  

function cal(arr )  
{  
return arr[ arr.length - 1 ] + arr[ arr.length - 2 ];  
}  

while ( fibno[ fibno.length - 1 ] < 4e+6 )  
{  
  fibno.push( cal(fibno) );  
}  

fibno.forEach( function(n)   
 {  
    if ( n % 2 === 0 )  
    {  
        sum += n;  
    }  
});  
return sum;  
}  

console.log(solution())
```

I don't understand how to print fibonacci series using html not using console for this java script

please help me.....

Comment: I think this question is better handeled at http://math.stackexchange.com

Comment: Also consider putting your efforts in the question, __SO__ is not a free coding service..

Comment: Do you just want to output the solution in HTML? I'm not exactly sure what you want. Also the fibonacci sequence starts with two 1's. 1 + 0 = 1, 1 + 1 = 2 and so on.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```js
function* fibonacci(){
  var fn1 = 0;
  var fn2 = 1;
  while (true){  
    var current = fn1;
    fn1 = fn2;
    fn2 = current + fn1;
    var reset = yield current;
    if (reset){
        fn1 = 0;
        fn2 = 1;
    }
  }
}

var sequence = fibonacci();

var sum = 0, x = sequence.next().value;

while(x < 4000000){
    if(x % 2 === 0){
         sum += x;  
    } 
    x = sequence.next().value;
}

console.log(sum);
document.getElementById('res').innerHTML = sum;
```

```html
<div id="res"></div>
```